# Find sum of numbers in line

Tags: python, file

This is what I have to do:

1. Read content of a text file, where two numbers separated by comma are on each line (like `10, 5\n`, `12, 8\n`, …)
2. Make a sum of those two numbers
3. Write into new text file two original numbers and the result of summation = like `10 + 5 = 15\n`, `12 + 8 = 20\n`, …

So far, I've got this:

```
import os
import sys

relative_path = "Homework 2.txt"
if not os.path.exists(relative_path):
    print "not found"
    sys.exit()

read_file = open(relative_path, "r")
lines = read_file.readlines()
read_file.close()
print lines

path_output = "data_result4.txt"
write_file = open(path_output, "w")

for line in lines:
    line_array = line.split()
    print line_array
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your last `for` loop look like this:

```
for line in lines:
    splitline = line.strip().split(",")
    summation = sum(map(int, splitline))
    write_file.write(" + ".join(splitline) + " = " + str(summation) + "\n")
```

One beautiful thing about that way is that you can have as many numbers as you want on a line, and it will still display correctly.

Comment: I got a error: ValueError: invalit literal for int() with base 10: "3,6". Im using  TXT FILE

Comment: Sorry for taking so long.  That is because I thought you would have `"3, 6"`, not `"3,6"`.  You just need to remove the space in the `.split()` call.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a good understanding of python to understand this.

First, read the file, and get all of the lines by splitting it with a line feed (`\n`)

For each expression, calculate the answer and write it. Remember, you need to cast the numbers to integers so that they can be added together.

```
with open('Original.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')

with open('answers.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for expression in lines: # expression should be in format '12, 8'
        nums = [int(i) for i in expression.split(', ')]

        f.write('{} + {} = {}\n'.format(nums[0], nums[1], nums[0] + nums[1]))
        # That should write '12 + 8 = 20\n'
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the input File is csv so just use the csv reader module in python.

**Input File Homework 2.txt**

```
1, 2
1,3
1,5
10,6
```

**The script**

```
import csv

f = open('Homework 2.txt', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)

result = []
for line in list(reader):
    nums = [int(i) for i in line]
    result.append(["%(a)s + %(b)s = %(c)s" % {'a' : nums[0], 'b' : nums[1], 'c' : nums[0] + nums[1] }])

f = open('Homework 2 Output.txt', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for line in result:
   writer.writerow(line)
```

**The output file is then Homework 2 Output.txt**

```
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 5 = 6
10 + 6 = 16
```

Comment: *Seems like the input File is csv*. Ummm... Not quite. The format that the data is written in may resemble a csv format, but this isn't a csv file - you'll just confuse the OP by saying this. It's just a plain, regular text file, in which case you're adding additional, unnecessary complexities to the code.

Comment: these is not right he said the input file is like: 10, 5\n, 12, 8\n, and this is just a csv input format

Comment: But it carries a `.txt` extension - not `.csv`. You're adding complexities, and proving my earlier point while at it.

Comment: that means nothing. But the format is csv, no doubt, so it's absolut ridiculous that you downvote my answer. No i dont add any complexity, where that i use a library to read and you just split it? As I think he is doing the work for university, a lot of your file are csv-formatted file in .txt file. So he can use this code for further work, too, and therefore the csv module is just fine.

Comment: The OP clearly isn't the brightest, and I get that, as the OP is still learning. There is no point in presenting a solution that uses a library that the OP has likely never heard of. It's important to be considerate of that. By adding (semi-) advanced formats of doing the task, you will end up confusing them more, which under no circumstance, should be the objective or result of an answer. The format is `.csv`, you're correct. But does the OP understand that? Has she heard of this "format?" As far as I can tell, no, and I wouldn't want such an answer to be presented to her.

Comment: So you downvote the answer, cause the OP isn't the brightest? I think its ok that to hear about csv, is a good thing here. Just to learn a little bit, too.

Comment: Now I feel like you're putting words in my mouth, and I find that rude. I down voted this answer because it wasn't a logical solution for the OP, that could successfully be integrated with his/her code with minimal confusion, and that you are adding advanced topics which are un-necessary.

Comment: Im using a .txt file

Comment: Man, I think you wrote a very good answer. My answer is correct, to and tried a little bit to get the OP further knowledge. I personally find, it's not ok to downvote a correct answer in a thread where you wrote an answer. @AliciaRijo just corrected the filenames. Your filename is "Homework 2.txt" or?